# Website is loading properly on a specific product

Tags: magento2.3, multi-website, loading

When we go to this product on this website the loading gif never goes away and lock the page:
https://www.rodin.no/catalog/product/view/id/178106/s/thule-7206-7215b-7214b-186046/category/1695/

This is the same product on another website, but no issue there.
https://takrails.no/thule-7206-7215b-7214b-186046.html

Anyone that know why this is happening?

Any help is appreciated

cheer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console says that it's an issue with the pricing.

I'd suggest removing var/view-preprocessed and var/page_cache, then running setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, and setup:static-content:deploy

Then clearing all caches

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, worked like a charm. Don't know how i could over look that :p